# Add environment variables in UWP with FullTrustProcessLauncher

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am trying to create environment variables in Windows through a UWP application using the [SetEnvironmentVariable method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0), but it seems that UWP as it runs in a sandbox prevents the application from being able to create environment variables.

**So I have created a console app to call it from UWP:**

```
  var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
  if (value == null)
  {
     var path = "pathTest";
     Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Test1", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
     Console.WriteLine("The environment variable has been created successfully");
  }
  else
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Environment variable already exists");
  }
```

**UWP code to run the console application that I have added in the application package:**

```
public class TestService : ITestService 
{
    public async Task ExecuteSampleApp()
    {
        await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
    }
}
```

and I have added the .exe in the same UWP application package, and I have added the necessary permissions (runFullTrust) in the Package.appxmanifest to be able to run external applications (that are in the application package), up to this point everything is fine , I can run the console app from my UWP app but it seems that the console app when run from the UWP app can't create the environment variable it's like access is taken away (I think somehow the app sandbox UWP adds the same security restrictions even to the .exe added in the application package), however if I run the same console application in the bin folder that is created when compiling the UWP app it works, the problem occurs only when the UWP app calls the .exe. Anyone have any other ideas on how I could create environment variables in UWP either with this approach I was following or with another?

And with this console app, would it be possible to run cmd commands bypassing the UWP sandbox security restrictions?

**Answer to @RoyLi-MSFT:**
No, there are no exceptions, the UWP application executes the console application and it shows the message "Environment variable already exists" detecting as if it already exists, however it has not created it at any time, it seems that the console application when it is executed by the UWP app it is not able to really obtain if the environment variable exists or not in the operating system and it returns an incorrect state (indicating that it exists when it does not). However, if the console application is run regardless, it does work, which suggests that it is a UWP problem that somehow isolates the console application to the same sandbox as the UWP app when it is executed by the UWP app. Regarding your other question with placing the exe file in the application package, I mean that I add in the Assets folder the console application in charge of registering the environment variables to be able to execute it with [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-20348) through UWP since it is the only way of running a win32 app from a sandbox environment.

**2º Answer to @RoyLi-MSFT:**
I use EnvironmentVariableTarget.User in my code, the code I had put here was an example (I have updated the example to clarify it), but I tried to use the 3 available enumerations: Process, User and Machine, the User type is the one that works correctly and is the one that I use in my console application, but as I mentioned before, when the UWP application is the one running the console application it cannot create the environment variable and the console shows: "The environment variable already exists" despite using EnvironmentVariableTarget.User.

**I clarify this point:** when the console application is run manually if it works, it only shows the message "The environment variable already exists" when the UWP application is in charge of executing it with [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-20348).

Comment: Have you tried to change the EnvironmentVariableTarget to User?  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Test1", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

Comment: I want to confirm something first. What do you mean by `can't create the environment variable`? Does it give an exception or something else? What's the behavior that you are getting? Another thing is that do you mean you put the exe file in the app package directly instead of using Windows Application Package Project(WAPP)?

Comment: @jerry Yes, I tried to use the 3 available enums: Process, User and Machine, but as I mentioned the console application works fine individually, the problem occurs when the UWP app runs the console application it is not able to register the environment variables.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I have updated the post with the answer to your questions as it was very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to create the environment variables. Through the UWP application we have to execute the console application and through the console application execute the CMD [setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) command through the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0) class, this is the code:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();    
var testPath = "c:\...";
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"setx testName + " \"" + testPath + "\"");
```

And with this we manage to bypass the restrictions that UWP has in the sandbox in which the applications are executed:

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document-[SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0), the Environment Variable you created is **stored in the current process**, which means the process environment block. I tested your code inside of a console app. Every time when I launched the console app, it shows `The environment variable has been created successfully`. If I tried to read the value after I write it, I could get the correct value. This behavior matches the document.

So the behavior you mentioned should be expected. You could try directly read the Environment Variable when you haven't closed the console app and you should be able to get the value you set. And @jerry's comment should make sense, you might need to try `SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget)` with other options like EnvironmentVariableTarget.User.

**Update:**

Based on your previous comment, you mentioned that you put the .exe file in the Assets folder of your UWP app. I would suggest you using the `Windows Application Package Project` to package the console app together with the UWP app. In that way under my test, the console app will correctly add the Environment Variable to the current user block and you could get it as you want.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new console app under the solution of your UWP app. Add the code you need.
2. Create a Windows Application Package Project, and add the console app and the UWP as application reference to the Package Project.
3. Declare the extension in the package manifest of the Package Project
4. launch it from the UWP app.

You could refer [Stafen's blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) for more details.

**And the result:**
[image]

Comment: I have added my answer in the post as it is very long.

Comment: @Tecnopresley So your code you post in your question is not the one that you are using in your app?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, but somewhat more simplified, I have omitted the real path for: "pathTest" and I had forgotten to add the EnvironmentVariableTarget parameter in the post, but otherwise it is identical.

Comment: @Tecnopresley That is a big difference if you missed the `EnvironmentVariableTarget`. After testing, the console app will work if you package it together with your UWP app using Windows Application Package Project. I'll update my answer later to share more details about it.

Comment: @Tecnopresley Please check the update

Comment: I just tested the repository referenced in the blog mentioned in your comment and added in Program.cs the lines to create environment variables, but it is not really saving the variable, you have tried to go to Advanced system settings -> Variables environment and verify if it really appears?